# Add a tooltip rectangle to NSToolBarItem's default view

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstoolbaritem

I have some `NSToolBarItems` to allow undo/redo in my app. I want them to show the name of undo/redo actions in their tooltip.

I can specify the tooltip of an `NSToolBarItem` vial its `toolTip` property. But I'm not sure when this property should be set. I haven't found a way to be notified  when the undo manager has recorded a new action to undo or redo.

It would be better to dynamically return the tooltip string when the user hovers the toolbar item. But this requires adding a tooltip rectangle to a view that I cannot access. Indeed, the `view` property of `NSToolBarItem` returns `nil` by default. It does not return `nil` if I set the `view` property with my own view, but a `NSToolBarItem` uses a private subclass of `NSButton` as view, by default. This subclass implements nice behaviours that `NSButton` doesn't. So I'd rather use the default view.

Is there a way to add a tooltip rectangle to an `NSToolBarItem`'s `view` that doesn't use a custom view? IOW, how can I access this view?

Comment: Subclass `NSToolBarItem` and override `toolTip`?

Comment: Good idea, but it seems that `toolTip` is not called when the toolTip should show, but only once when the toolbar item is added to the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hack `NSToolbarItem`. Use the `NSUndoManagerCheckpointNotification` notification on your undo manager. Every time it is called you can update the tooltip of the two toolbar bar items.

```
[NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter addObserverForName:NSUndoManagerCheckpointNotification object:self.undoManager queue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue usingBlock:^(NSNotification * _Nonnull note) {
    NSString *undoTitle = self.undoManager.undoMenuItemTitle;
    NSString *redoTitle = self.undoManager.redoMenuItemTitle;
    // Update the toolbar items' tooltips
}];
```

You can also access the relevant undo manager via `note.object` in the block.

Comment: I tried it, but this notification is sent dozens of time for each user action. I managed to access the toolbar item view (by traversing the view hierarchy) and to add a tooltip rectangle. This is is not the most elegant, but I can update the tooltip only when it shows.

Comment: Does it matter if this notification is sent more often than needed? It still lets you correctly update the tooltips. No need to dig into the private subview structure of the toolbar item.

Comment: In that case I'd rather use my previous solution, which was to update the tooltips in `validateUserInterfaceItem`. This is called for every user action (even if not undoable), but only once per action, while `NSUndoManagerCheckpointNotification` can be sent dozen of times in a run loop.